# how to optimize the use of union operator where both query are similar?

Tags: mysql, union

here is the problem . i have a Mysql query :

```
select * from employee where name ='xyz' and salary <10000
union 
select * from employee where name ='xyz' and salary >100000
```

as some part of query is repetitive how can i optimize it.

Comment: You could use the `or` operator instead of doing a Union

`select * from employee where name ='xyz' and salary <10000 or salary >100000`

Comment: @goonerify: or fragment has to be in parenthesis.

Comment: @IvanH Good Catch. It should be `select * from employee where name ='xyz' and (salary <10000 or salary >100000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to UNION the two results, as the one is always a subset of the others. If you select for salary > 10000, you already *have* the cases with salary >100000 included. Why would select them again selarately and merge the results??

Comment: true ,changed condition , how to optimize. i dont want to do repetitive work as my table is too huge.

Comment: Use an OR: `where salary < 10000 or salary > 100000`, or use a negated between: `NOT BETWEEN 10000 AND 100000`. UNION is very rarely really needed, you can nearly always replace it with better (more efficient) conditions.